# MTU and SSH connection

Tags: networking, ssh

[SSH connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0DVK.png)
My system is Ubuntu 20.04 **MTU (maximum transmission unit ) size 1500 default** and try to remote connection another systems over ssh protocol

Question is ssh connection successfully done but in wireshark **i saw the packets above 1500 bytes size.**

I didn't know what is happening there.please someone explain **how packets handle by ssh protocal above 1500 byte**

thank you advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mtu is handled on the **3rd** OSI level and ssh is 7 level. So ssh knows nothing about mtu, fragmentation happens in the system's tcp/ip stack (kernel) later, after ssh sent it's data to a socket.

It would be easier if you provided some screenshots, but I believe you saw packets **before** fragmentation.

Comment: Thank for your reply . 
i added Screenshot above question . In that image client : key exchange Init packet size 1570 bytes but MTU 1500 didn't know where the fragmentation was done and aslo i need to debug the fragmented packets .In wireshark i saw above 1500 byte thats why i need to know about
**how fragmentation process done by the ssh protocal ? & how to see the fregmented packets ?**

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my answer

Comment: I understand your answer bro . there is no no relation between MTU and above 1500 byte in ssh protocal i clear about it . so once 3rd layer pass packets to other layer. then socket will handle the packets ... right ?

Thank you for reply

Comment: right :) I've asked because you repeated the question

Comment: Hi. Im not sure if I understand your answer properly. Here's a screenshot of my wireshark https://imgur.com/a/HY709mQ showing that my SSH client key exchange is 1588 IPv4 Frame Size, but my MTU is 1200 *and* "do not fragment" bit is set. How is it even possible? I don't see any ICMP packets in the Wireshark that tell SSH to reduce their packet size.